# Doctrine array form

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm working in Symfony, & I have a form as follow :

```
 $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('group')
            ->add('category')
            ->add('expirationDate', DateType::class)
            ->add('activeDay', ChoiceType::class, array(
                'choices' => array(
                    'mon'    => '  Monday',
                    'tue'    => '  Tuesday',
                    'wed'    => '  Wednesday',
                    'thu'    => '  Thursday',
                    'fri'    => '  Friday',
                    'sat'    => '  Saturday',
                    'sun'    => '  Sunday',
                ),
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true,
            ))
            ->add('Save', SubmitType::class)
```

& for the activeDay type in doctrine is an array :

```
/**
     * @var \ArrayObject
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="active_day", type="array", nullable=true)
     */
    private $activeDay;
```

now, I'm trying to get all the data as a table, so how can I get the ActiveDays as follow : `Mon,Thur` ?

**EDIT 1** : A table as this one

[image]

EDIT2 : well, the ActiveDays column now is shown as  following : [image]

What can I do to display it as : `Mon,Thur,Fri` or `Mon,Sat`, may be something can I do it in the repository?

Comment: What do you mean by `get all the data as a table`?

Comment: @MECU you can see my edit

Comment: Are you talking about handling when the form is submitted?

Comment: well the data I got are as they are stocked in the database, even the array of the active days .. that's why I'm asking if there is any idea about how to convert it into a simple string while list the data in a table

Comment: Not sure I fully understand, but [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) may be what you want. `implode(',', $activeDay)`